# sinc function in terms of Hermite function

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions

Is there any formula which represent the sinc function $\operatorname{\rm sinc}(x)=\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ (its expansion) in terms of the Chebychev-Hermite function?

Answer (score 5):

Denote the Chebyshev-Hermite functions as
$$
   \varphi_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n }{\sqrt{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}} H_n(x) \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} 
$$
where $H_n(x)$ denote the $n$-th [Hermite orthogonal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

Because $\varphi_n(x)$ form complete orthonormal system, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi_n(x) \varphi_m(x) \mathrm{d} x = \delta_{n,m}$ we have
$$
   \operatorname{\mathrm{sinc}}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \varphi_n(x)
$$
where $c_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi_n(x) \operatorname{\mathrm{sinc}}(x) \mathrm{d} x$. Now, due to parity $c_{2m+1} = 0$.

Notice that $c_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{\varphi}_n(\omega) \hat{\operatorname{\rm sinc}}(\omega) \mathrm{d}  \omega $. Since
$$
   \hat{\varphi}_{2n}(\omega) = (-1)^n \varphi_{2n}(\omega)  \qquad
   \hat{\operatorname{\rm sinc}}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} [ -\pi < \omega < \pi ]
$$
we have
$$
   c_{2n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \varphi_{2n}(\omega) \mathrm{d} \omega = (-1)^n \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{0}^\pi \varphi_{2n}(\omega) \mathrm{d} \omega
$$
Now, using the explicit expression for the Hermite polynomials:
$$
   \varphi_{2n}(\omega) = \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{2^n \pi^{1/4}}  \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\omega^2}{2}} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \frac{(2\omega)^k}{(2k)! (n-k)!}
$$
we have
$$
   c_{2n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{2^n \pi^{1/4}} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!(n-k)!} 2^{3 k - 1/2} \gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\pi^2}{2} \right)
$$
where $ \gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\pi^2}{2} \right)$ stands for the [incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2#E1).

Here is a verification in *Mathematica*:

[image]

Copy-paste ready input:

```
In[77]:= Table[
  Sqrt[2/Pi] Sqrt[(2 n)!]/(2^n Pi^(1/4))
     Sum[(-1)^k/((2 k)! (n - k)!) 2^(3 k - 1/2)
       Gamma[k + 1/2, 0, Pi^2/2], {k, 0, n}] - 
   Integrate[(HermiteH[2 n, x] E^(-(x^2/2)))/Sqrt[
     2^(2 n) (2 n)! Sqrt[\[Pi]]] Sinc[Pi x], {x, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}], {n, 0, 4}] // FullSimplify

Out[77]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: What you have called $\Gamma_{k+1/2}\left(0,\frac{\pi^2}{2} \right)$ I think is [more commonly denoted](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E1) as $\gamma\left(k+\frac12,\frac{\pi^2}{2}\right)$. As you know, *Mathematica* only supports the lower incomplete gamma function implicitly...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, you have a point. I will edit the post to change that.